# How to send money to a friend in Europe?

Tags: india, money-transfer

It's my first question on this website. Please guide me through the steps to send 143-150 Euros to a friend who is in urgent need.

Some details:
I have my bank account in India, my credit and debit cards work internationally, but I have never done an international payment before.

I have the required account number, IBAN number and Swift code.

Kindly help me as it's very urgent.

Comment: Have you asked your bank how to do this? If it's urgent, a small fee is not worth the effort of trying to avoid or reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options to send money internationally. You can send it through PayPal (assuming that both you and your friend have a PayPal account). You can also send it through money services such as Western Union (assuming you can both get to a WU location). Or, you can use popular apps such as Venmo for sending money.